# How to color code textarea content with Angular 7?

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular. There is a textarea element

```
 <textarea rows="17" class="form-control" formControlName="sqlCode"
```

When user types in sql I want it to be color coded. For example **SELECT** should be in blue, **FROM** , **WHERE**. . . simplest possible color coding for SQL. How can I achieve this? I tried looking up documentation however could not find a way to change color for textarea

Comment: Angular doesn't do this out of the box. Look for a npm package that will do this for you. Or, roll your own.

Comment: Thank you very much. which npm package does this? i could not find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ngx-highlight](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-highlightjs) to provide syntax highlight feature in your code. This works out of the box with Angular.